# Why can I not `$ sudo echo "hello" > file` on file with permissions 000?

Tags: bash

In Bash, the following sequence of commands is entered:

```
$ touch testfile
$ chmod 000 testfile
$ sudo echo "hello" > testfile
```

The last command fails. I always believed, with `sudo` I can do anything.
Funnily enough, I can `rm testfile` without `sudo`, all I'm asked is to confirm.

Comment: You have write access to the directory in which the file is located so the file can be removed (the directory is modified, not the file).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The redirection is being done by your original shell, which has your normal permissions, not the elevated permissions from `sudo`. You need to perform the redirection in the process run by `sudo`:

```
sudo bash -c 'echo "hello" > testfile'
```

Comment: Or `echo "hello" | sudo tee testfile`